# Не работают агрегатные функции в MySQL

Tags: phpmyadmin, sql, mysql

Всем привет.
Немогу понять в чем дело, не работают агрегатные функции, выдает все время одну и туже ошибку. Пробывал уже разные варианты с разными базами и хостингами. Просьба подсказать в чем может быть проблема.
Вот скрин ошибки:
http://snag.gy/GdDHj.jpg

Благодарю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте убрать пробел между SUM и скобкой ()
Должно получится так SUM(), а ни как сейчас SUM_()

Comment: Да все верно, с пробелом проблема была:)
Благодарю.